# No audio playback on mobile device

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is the link
http://breakingbadbutton.com/

Basically you hit the button and it plays back an audio file. I can't figure out why it doesn't work on iPhone/iPads...

The script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
  var sounds = [
            "audio/basement.mp3",
             "audio/half.mp3",
             "audio/science.mp3",
             "audio/tone.mp3",
             "audio/minerals.mp3",
             "audio/sticks.mp3",
             "audio/gatorade.mp3",
             "audio/roll.mp3",
             "audio/right.mp3",
             "audio/knocks.mp3",
             "audio/hotdogs.mp3",
             "audio/keys.mp3",
             "audio/heil.mp3",
             "audio/money.mp3",
             "audio/ours.mp3",
             "audio/pass.mp3"],
   pickSound = 0;

$("button").click(function() {
   $('#soundDiv').html("<embed src=\""+ sounds[pickSound] +"\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\" />");
   pickSound = (pickSound + 1) % sounds.length;
});
```

});

Comment: Audio tags require user interaction for them to play. So embedding it into the page with auto play simply won't work. Look into the webaudio API http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/

Answer (score 0):

You should use something a bit more upto date, i believe `<embed>` has be deprecated in HTML4.01

Instead, use the `<audio>` tag for this sort of thing.. [Example here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio#Examples)

You can add attributes like `autoplay` etc, they're all [available here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio#Attributes)

Here's a fiddle of the player changing mp3, although the mp3's arent available so they wont play here obviously :-) http://jsfiddle.net/mP3zM/

Comment: I can't seem to get it to play.

Comment: like i said, it won't play on that example as the audio files aren't available, but if you implement that into your code it will work as expected